# html5 pattern that will not allow only numbers but accepts everything

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have an input text field in my form but i don't know how to filter the input that can all letters and special characters but will not accept numbers.

```
<input  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}" maxlength="25" type="text" required="required" style="height:20px"  value="">
```

I tried to omit the pattern but it still doesn't accept when I enter my middle name "pacaña".

I'm wondering why it doesn't accept the ñ?

Here's the solution I did

`pattern="[^\d\uhhhh]"`

Now it does not allow alphabets? How can I allow alphabets?

Comment: depending on the regex implementation `\w{1,25}` might work

Comment: still doesn't accept ñ sir.

Comment: You should clarify your earlier question, instead of reposting it in a slightly modified form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex has the NOT operator ^.  E.g. [^0-9].  Match any single character that is not in the set.

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html - Negated Character Classes. For more info.

Comment: okay.. ill read this.. thankyou

Comment: i think even if i apply the negated character class will still not accept ñ

Comment: Please note that will also accept symbols.

Answer (score 1):

If you want anything other than digits, use the following pattern:

```
[^\d]
```

Comment: but it doesn't accept ñ character... hmmmn..

Comment: I need to accept ñ character sir.